# Unity3D how to change sprite in SpriteRenderer at runtime with programaticly generated sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm having this problem with sprites in my Unity3D project. Basiclly I can't change sprite in SpriteRenderer component during runtime. During my research I've only seen solutions that require you to have the sprite pre-loaded, but I can't because it's generated based on the users input image.
So what happens is the user can change the background of the "game" by inputing his own photo from his computer. I get the photo in and everything and I generate a sprite from it, but when I change the base sprite with his sprite, nothing happens. The base sprite is still showing. If I put the background sprite on a panel's Image in canvas, then everything works great, but if I do the same with SpriteRenderer then nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
public class UploadImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject background;
    public Sprite sp;
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void ImageUploaderCaptureClick();

    public void setTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(texture.width / 2, texture.height / 2));
        background.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sp;
    }


    IEnumerator LoadTexture(string url)
    {
        WWW image = new WWW(url);
        yield return image;
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        image.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
        Debug.Log("Loaded image size: " + texture.width + "x" + texture.height);
        setTexture(texture);
    }

    void FileSelected(string url)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadTexture(url));
    }

    public void OnButtonPointerDown()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        string path = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Open image", "", "jpg,png,bmp");
        if (!System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            FileSelected("file:///" + path);
#else
        ImageUploaderCaptureClick ();
#endif
    }
}
```

I can't have the background on an image in canvas because other game objects lose transparency and if I set the alpha on image too low, then when game objects move, it leaves everything blurry.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting the sprites pivot wrong when generating the sprite. Your sprite should even be displayed at the moment but its far away from where you expect it to be. 
Change your code to something like this:

```
sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```